# Linear equation with no solutions (parallel lines)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose 
I have two equations

```
-x + y = 0
-x + y = -2
```

Suppose I don't know geometry, I don't know slopes,  suppose I have just started reading algebraic equations .

after solving those above equation .. I will get stuck to

```
-2 = 0
```

answer will be those equations don't have solutions...

But if I ask why? Why cant they have solutions. what will be the answer in terms of algebra.

I know -2 is not equal to 0 but those are mathematical values, but what is answer in terms of algebraic definition or anything?

Comment: Draw two parallel lines. Do they intersect?

Comment: i have already mentioned ,Presume myself as kid who don't know geometry.

Comment: But if you don't know geometry *and* the fact that substracting the two equations give $-2=0$ is not enough, then how more basic can you get ?

Comment: This is still unclear: if you know "next to nothing" about geometry, what would induce you to believe that an equation can be used to represent the set of coordinates that corresponds to a set of points lying along a "line"?  (Analytic geometry is a modern invention -- less than 400 years old -- and the connection between algebra and "classical" geometry was by no means obvious.)  One has to come to accept at some stage that the lack of algebraic solutions to the system you give can be interpreted as the absence of intersection points of the two lines so described.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I was teaching Algebra to my younger sister, she asked me the same question what I have asked here.I obviously can't explain her in terms of geometry because she haven't yet started with geometry and slopes, And I am looking for possible explanation to her without using geometry, why above those two equation cant have any solutions

Comment: Your post title then is misleading and is the cause of many of the comments that followed, as well as two of the answers posted.  The accepted answer is to the point ( for any choice of $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ , $ \ y - x \ $ can't take on two different values).  There is no reason to bring up a geometrical interpretation for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the reflexive property, x=x.$$ $$
y=x-2
$$ $$
y=x
$$ $$
The reflexive property also says y=y.
$$ $$
Therefore, x=x-2. $$ $$
This contradicts the reflexive property, x=x.$$ $$
For any solution to exist, it would have to contradict the reflexive property. But the reflexive property is a fundamental algebraic axiom, ergo no solution can exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to not accept slopes / any geometric construction, then the best that I can think of in pure algebra is the number of common solutions between the lines.

1. If two lines are parallel, then they will *never* intersect (that is, they will have $0$ solutions in common).
2. If both the lines are the *same line*, then they will have **infinite** solutions in common.
3. If the lines are not parallel, then they will have $1$ unique solution in common

The number of solutions of a system of equations can be computed by writing the equation as a matrix equation

$$
A x = b
$$

where $A$ is your coefficient matrix, $x$ is your vector of variables, and $b$ is your constants vector.

For this problem,

$$
-x + y = 0 \\
-x +y = -2 \\ \\
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & +1 \\ -1 &+1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\y \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence,

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & +1 \\ -1 &+1\end{bmatrix} \\
x =\begin{bmatrix} x \\y \end{bmatrix} \\
b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution to the system $Ax = b$ is $x = A^{-1}b$. Hence, **A must be invertible for solutions to exist**

In our case, the determinant of $A$, $|A| = 0$ since it has the same row $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & +1 \end{pmatrix}$, hence the determinant will be $0$ and the matrix $A$ is non-invertible.

Since the matrix $A$ is non-invertible, *but* we need to achieve some non-zero value on the other side, the system of equations has no solution, and hence the lines are parallel

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. This means there are no coordinates $(x,y)$ that satisfy both equations *at the same time*. This means there is is no point $P=(x,y)$ the can lie on both lines at the same time. Hence, the lines *do not intersect*. By definition the lines are parallel then.

Comment: Presume myself as kid who don't know geometry.

Comment: What are looking for then?